# How to download an html file in a BlackBerry application

Tags: java, html, blackberry

I need to scrape information from a web page and put it into my application, but I can't figure out how to download the file into my application in the first place.  Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use my [simple page scraping](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/ttips/scraping/) code. You'll also want to use Versatile Monkey's [networking helper class](http://www.versatilemonkey.com/blog/index.php/2009/06/24/networking-helper-class/) to open the HTTP connection using the best path on a BlackBerry.

Comment: Okay so I have taken your code and tried to implement it into my project, but when I try to call the constructor for the ScraperTest class, it gives me an error that says "uncaught: SecurityException". Do you know why this is?

Comment: This is how I initialize the constructor: `ScraperTest test; test = new ScraperTest();`