# Download a file from a server with a BlackBerry app

Tags: blackberry, java-me, connection

I want to download a file from a server via the internet with a BlackBerry app.
It is not important which protocol is used: FTP, HTTP or something else would be fine. I just need the user to click "download" button and then the app downloads this file from a server.

I have no idea how it can be done. I have tried a few solutions. In one I need a HttpConnectorFactory but this is not in my API.

I have searched for an answer to my question for days, but I haven't found a solution that works.

Links to solutions I have tried:

- [How to download an html file in a BlackBerry application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007127/how-to-download-an-html-file-in-a-blackberry-application)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290988/downloading-a-pdf-file-from-a-webserver-in-blackberry-java-application
- [Networking Helper Class](http://www.versatilemonkey.com/blog/index.php/2009/06/24/networking-helper-class/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this -

```java
ConnectionFactory connFact = new ConnectionFactory();
ConnectionDescriptor connDesc = connFact.getConnection(your_url);
HttpConnection httpConn = (HttpConnection) connDesc.getConnection();
try {
    httpConn.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.GET);
    InputConnection inputConn = (InputConnection) httpConn;
    InputStream is = inputConn.openInputStream();
    byte[] data =IOUtilities.streamToBytes(is);
    //the value in data will be the bytes of your file.
    // now if you want to save the file, you can do it here......
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```